# How to check if React PWA uses latest version?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'd like to show my user that an update is available. Therefore I need to know how to check if he already uses the latest version.

Currently I set an item in localStorage called "updateAvailable" as soon as the serviceWorker tells me that there is a new version available. That works fine.

What doesn't work fine although is when I'd like to set "updateAvailable" to false. The item isn't set in localStorage.

**How do I set this item in localStorage when the latest version of my PWA is used?**

```
function registerValidSW(swUrl: string, config?: Config) {
  console.log("test 5")
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        if (installingWorker == null) {
          return;
        }
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the updated precached content has been fetched,
              // but the previous service worker will still serve the older
              // content until all client tabs are closed.
              console.log(
                'New content is available and will be used when all ' +
                  'tabs for this page are closed. See [hidden link]'
              );
              localStorage.setItem("updateAvailable", "true")

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                config.onUpdate(registration);
              }
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');
              localStorage.setItem("updateAvailable", "false")

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                config.onSuccess(registration);
              }
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
}
```

Comment: are you getting any errors? have you tried using a debugger to pinpoint the problem? have you tried anything else that might shed some light on the issue?

Comment: Yes, I added console.logs all over the serviceworker file, but none did log to the console when the latest version was used. The only thing that helps me partially here is that it tells me that the latest version got installed. Yet I need to know when this version is also in use.

Answer (score 1):

that code block only executes in the 'onupdatefound' event.

Comment: Thanks! Where should I place it then?